# how to get Firefox build id?

Tags: java, firefox, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Does anyone know how to get Firefox build id (that string consisted of 14 digit) in java/selenium tests?

you can check it by accessing in the browser, about:config then search by buildID you will see the string there, but how can be accessed through java tests in order to be displayed?

kind regards

Comment: What is your _usecase_ exactly to retrieve get `Firefox build id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
Capabilities cap = ((RemoteWebDriver) driver).getCapabilities();
String browserVersion = (String)cap.getCapability("browserVersion");
```

Comment: applying this I will get the firefox version: 61.0a1 not the buildID that I will expect (like: 20180402111808)

Comment: Try (String)cap.getCapability("version"). And also see here https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities  if it won't help, try to get list of capabilities in debug mode, and see which key you should use, to get your build id

Comment: So you can also go on about:support and parse build Id

Comment: thanks for tip, I managed to take the build id using the String text value from buildID field